# Rails model and scaffold for Posts and Likes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to generate a model and scaffold for a "Like" feature in my application. The application has a "Post" model and a "User" model. The users can "Like" the different posts (just like any other social network software)

I am using mongoid and ROR 5.

The User model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :created_at, type: String
  field :updated_at, type: String

  has_many :posts
end
```

The Post model:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :created_at, type: String
  field :updated_at, type: String

  belongs_to :user        
end
```

What would be a proper "Like" model? My best guess was that the "Like" should be embedded in the User model, and "belongs_to" a Post.

How do I scaffold the Like model? 
How would the "User" or the "Post" model change as a result?

Comment: You can use `act_as_votable` gem . please check here https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

Comment: @Vishal `act_as_votable` only works with `ActiveRecord::Base` class, but he is using `Mongoid::Document`

Comment: @yeuem1vannam Ohh sorry, i didn't notice that.

Comment: Instead of adding `created_at`, `updated_at` manually, you can use http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Timestamps

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you use the collection.

When you embed the `Like` collection in `User`, but want to display like count on every posts, then the embedded solution seems redundant. And vice versa with embed to `Post`

The easiest way that you can create an independent collection `Like` without affecting `User` or `Post`

```
class Like
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :user_id, type: String
  field :post_id, type: String
end
```

And use it as SQL relation ( same with the relation between `User` and `Post` )

```
class User
  # ...
  has_many :likes
end

class Post
  # ...
  has_many :likes
end
```

You need some extra check when creating `Like` to make sure a user can like a post only once.

For extra speed ( without care about structure ), you can skip the `Like` collection and embed references directly to `User` and `Post`. Ofcourse this way need more extra check when do the **like** action

```
class User
  # ...
  field :liked_post_ids, type: Array, default: []
end

class Post
  # ...
  field :liked_user_ids, type: Array, default: []
end
```

In NoSQL world, the structure depends on how you use the data, not how beautiful it is. But in my opinion, you should create the independent `Like` collection.

Comment: Can't we do `belongs_to :user` in `Like` model instead of `field :user_id, type: String` ? Similarly for `:post`.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Yes, you can do it. The field name just for clarification.